# Removing a program in Ubuntu--unable to find package name

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I want to remove program "fio" from my Ubuntu. First, tried

```
apt-get remove fio
```

but it did not work. Then I tried to find its package name by

```
whereis fio 
dpkg-query -S /usr/local/bin/fio
```

but dpkg-query says "no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/fio". Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the program? Files from Ubuntu packages (`.deb` files) are usually not installed in `/usr/local/`.

Comment: Cannot remember! Probably using source code and make etc.

Comment: I see it as an un-installed package. I am pretty sure now that I have installed from source code using ./configure && make && make install .

Comment: Did you try to run `make uninstall` from the same directory as `make install`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @DavidFoerster [fio's Makefile has an `install` target](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/dbab52955aeb0b58cc88c8eff1b1c2239241f0bd/Makefile#L560) but not an `uninstall` target...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the problem is moot, but **for the future**:

***Always use the same removal method as the installation method.***

Therefore, use the following priority in installing software

1. Install/remove from the standard Ubuntu repositories using the GUI of the Ubuntu Software center.
2. Use the TUI of [`aptitude`](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude)
3. `apt-get install szPackageName` to install and `apt-get purge szPackageName` to completely remove and `apt-get remove szPackageName` to remove the application, but not its configuration files.
4. Download and install a .deb file: use `dpgk --install szPackageName` and `dpgk --purge szPackageName` and `dpgk --remove szPackageName` as above.
5. So *if you do download and build from source*, use [`CheckInstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to be able to remove more easily in the future.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)